# For a Pinescript (version 5) library function, how do I declare the variable type of a "timeframe / resolution" function parameter?

Tags: pine-script

For a Pinescript (version 5) library function, how do I declare the variable type of a "timeframe / resolution" parameter? In the following sample, how must "resoVar" be declared in the function?

```
//@version=5

library("My Library")

export testFunction(<variable type> resoVar, string someString) =>
     <function code>
```

The value will be generated from user input using:

`resoInput = input(title="resoVar", type=input.resolution, defval='60')`

and then will be processed with the aforesaid library function:

`testFunction(resoInput, "test")`

I can't seem to locate in the documentation for the newly released version 5 of Pinescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for resolution input has changed in v5 :

```
resoInput = input.timeframe(title = "resoVar", defval = '60')
```

You should be able to declare the variable type in the function with the string type.

```
export testFunction(string resoVar, string someString) =>
```

Be aware you can't use `request.security()` in libraries. So unless you're using the resolution argument another way such as `ta.change(time(resoVar)) != 0` then you may need to reconsider how to refactor your library / code to take this into account.